# Sort array according to length and smallest lexicographically Python

Tags: python

I have following task

1. determine the longest strings that have not yet been written out
2. among the strings with the longest length that were not written out, select the smallest lexicographically
3. write out the selected line, go to the first item, if there are still unwritten lines

I have following code

```
strings = ['5', 'z', 'yy', 'y', 'zyz', 'zzz']
strings = [x for x in strings if not x.isdigit()]

result = []
for _ in range(0, len(strings)):
    value = max(strings, key=len)
    result.append(strings.pop(strings.index(value)))

print(result)
```

Example: `input array ['5', 'z', 'yy', 'y', 'zyz', 'zzz'] -> output ['zyz', 'zzz', 'yy', 'y', 'z']`

But i have an erorr here, my program returns `['zyz', 'zzz', 'yy', 'z', 'y']`

The other correct example `input array [5, dbccdacaac, abcddbbaab, ccaaaccdab, cdaadbcbdc, dcabdabccb] -> output [abcddbbaab, ccaaaccdab, cdaadbcbdc, dbccdacaac, dcabdabccb]`

How to sort array according to length and smallest lexicographically ?

Comment: Have you tried radix sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
sorted(strings,key=lambda x: (-len(x),x))
```

Comment: Or just add reversed keyword

Comment: Reverse won't work because you need decreasing length and increasing lexicographic order

Comment: Sure. Just depends which element of the key you negate.

Answer (score 1):

just add : **strings.sort()**
before appending these values to result list.

This works.